# Apply superposition principle to compute current in the $2Ω$ resistor shown in the figure. All resistors are in ohms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

So in this question what I tried to do was first remove the 6A source and then try to apply the current divider rule according to which the current **I = 24 x (4/12) = 8A** and then remove the 24A source and then again try to apply the current divider rule according to which the current i = **6 x (6/12) = 3A** and the final answer I arrived at was **I(total) = I-i(cause 3A is in opposite direction) = 5A**. Is it the correct way to apply the current divider rule in this question?

Ignore the blue dash in the question.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Well it was not a homework question but more of 'confirming that what I did was right' kind of question. But anyways a helpful answer was provided so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure is correct.

In superposition you keep only one source and *disconnect* all other sources: (i) voltage sources are replaced by short circuits, and (ii) current sources are replaced by open circuits. Solve for the current and then repeat the procedure for all sources in the circuit. The final current is then sum of currents in all sub-cases, whereas you must pay special attention to current direction, which you did in your solution.

Please note that superposition is an extremely slow procedure to solve for currents. Better way to calculate potentials for all nodes is to use *Millman method* from which it is trivial to calculate currents. See here for a simple example how the Millman method is used: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/686318/149541